# How to type a variable to be instance of a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js

I have a component that requires a component instance as a prop to work. I need TS to throw an error if that prop is not an instance of a specific component.

How can I achieve that? Is there a utility type for this?

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  button: InstanceOfReactElement<RequiredButton>
}

function MyComponent({ button, ...props }: MyComponentProps) {
  ...
}

function RequiredButton(props) { ... }

// ❌ need typescript to throw error here if `button` is not `<RequiredButton />`
<MyComponent button={<p>whatever</p>} />

// ✅ no error here since `button` is instance of 'RequiredButton'
<MyComponent button={<RequiredButton />} />
```

Comment: React instances are just `JSX.Element`

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to tell the compiler to statically analyze the instance of a react component?

Comment: AFAIK, it is impossible. However, you can use `React.createElement` built in function. It might give you some sort of static analyze